# Iss claim not valid Keycloak

Tags: spring, spring-boot, authentication, jwt, keycloak

I use the keycloak service to login my web app. Use as a backend spring with oauth 2.0 security. When I go to make a request with postman using the bearer token obtained from keycloak it gives me an error 401 and also in the text of the answer next to the `www-Authenticate` entry it tells me:

`Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The iss claim is not valid", error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"`.

How could I solve this problem?

Comment: What's the value of `iss` claim in your token?

Comment: http://localhost:8080/realms/demo

Comment: It is not an iss, you can see it go https://jwt.io/  To view your token claims you can paste it into https://jwt.io/ at Encoded section. you can see iss at payload section.

Comment: Sorry it can iss, I think this problem is expired token. You can test extend an access token lifespan. The default time is 5 minutes, you can go "demo" realms menu "Roalm Settings" then select "Tokens" tab in Keycloak UI, change Access Token Lifespan to extend more time, press save button, then try again.

Comment: when the token has expired it tells me

Comment: @programmerconsociatio, the token's exp tell the time of expiration
example  "exp": 1656930862" can convert a human readable format
https://esqsoft.com/javascript_examples/date-to-epoch.htm
it is "Mon Jul 04 2022 06:34:22 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"

Comment: when the token has expired it tells me token has expired, instead at the moment it just tells me that there is a problem in the issue claim. To be clearer what I do is:
1. I get the token from keycloak through postman
2. I send the token in the header to the server spring which verifies if the token is correct by connecting to keycloak

Comment: @programmerconsociatio, if expired access token, get new access token with refresh token. The refresh expires more longer period. I less experience Spring Boot with Keycloak but it is common steps. Postman just debugging purpose use it. It should not be includes production environment. Generally, Front End for UI (node js - Angular or React App),  Keycloak (IDP server) and Spring Boot(back end - resource server) for Rest API server.  UI connect to Keycloak for log-in/out then UI got access token, UI call to Back-end for call with access token.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Spring config value must be **exactly** the same as `iss` claim value. Even trailing slash, if any, is important.

Do as @BenchVue wrote in comment: open one of access-token JWTs in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io), copy  `iss` claim value and paste it in spring conf.

Another option is to remove the issuer validation from the JWT decoder: provide `jwk-set-uri` in your conf and remove `issuer-uri`, but be aware that in this case the token validation will be done only using its signature.

Comment: thx for reminder about trailing slash :)

Comment: Oh man. A big thank you. Its been days struggling with this issue not until I found your solution.

Answer (score 1):

the OAuth properties in application.properties must be the same as the Keycloak address:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://keycloak-IP:Port/auth/realms/XXX
```

Answer (score 0):

in my case : i used wrongly

> 127.0.0.1 instade of **localhost**

in config

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=http://localhost:8080/realms/master
```

beacaus it is **localHost** in access_token
[image]