# JWT doesn't contain iss claim

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm using a Spring Boot application as a resource server, and it needs to validate the JWTs. But I'm always getting the following error on a request:

> Bearer error="invalid_token", error_description="An error occurred while attempting to decode the Jwt: The iss claim is not valid",  error_uri="https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750#section-3.1"

The issurer URI is set correct in the `application.properties` by the following line:

```
spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver.jwt.issuer-uri=<IssuerUri>
```

But I found out, that my JWT doesn't contain a claim which contains the issuer URI. Is there any way to override the validation for the issuer URI in Spring Boot?

I already tried to find a config in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` configurations to toggle the validation off. But I haven't found anything.

Comment: ave you looked at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72854439/iss-claim-not-valid-keycloak ?

Comment: I know my problem isnt that Spring Boot doesnt have the Issuer URI. My Problem is that the jwt doesnt contain the claim `iss`

Comment: Sounds like something not right from the issuer side... But if you cannot do anything there then you probably need to create your own JwtDecoder Bean to handle this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the configuration I was looking for. You can override the issuer uri from the JWT in the `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter`

```java
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.oauth2ResourceServer().jwt().jwkSetUri("<IssuerUri>");
}
```

Comment: Your answer is more or less the same as the answer in the link from grekier and Harsh. You can do it with a property or by implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Keycloak as Auth Server, this error can sometimes happen on local dev setup, when the Auth Server and Resource Server are running in a docker container, and the token was requested using the access token URL which points to localhost instead of the Auth Server's container name.

If you provide the host name of the access token url as `localhost`, Keycloak will add the iss claims to the token with the host as `localhost`, now when the resource server running in a container tries to validate the token against the Auth Server, it tries to contact it's own `localhost` instead of calling the AuthServer container.

The solution in this case, is to provide the container name as host name while requesting access token.

I explained this in detail in this video - youtu.be/5_EXMJbhLY4?t=2519